# React Native FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I made the necessary setups for react native on windows. Then I created my project with the command "npx react-native init projectname". Then I ran my project with "npx react-native run-android" command but I get the following errors.

```
C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Masaüstü\mobile\project>npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Masaüstü\mobile\project\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Masaüstü\mobile\project\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Masaustu\mobile\project\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 195

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\MasaÃ¼stÃ¼\mobile\project\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Masaüstü\mobile\project\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.

C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Masaüstü\mobile\project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to install the latest version of @react-native-community/cli-platform-android

```
npm i @react-native-community/cli-platform-android
```

then go to the android directory and clean gradlew by the following command

```
cd android && gradlew clean
```

go back to your main directory and run app

```
cd.. && react-native run-android
```